# When I switch the IIS App Pool to "Classic" my Home Realm Discovery page doesn't show up

Tags: asp.net, iis, adfs2.0

Background:

I'm trying to do work on the Home Realm Discovery page-- ultimately trying to inject a WHR clause to bypass the Home Realm Discovery page.

What I'm trying to do won't work unless I switch the application pool from "Integrated" to "Classic" ( I get errors in the browser) .

[image: Switching IIS Application Pool to "Classic"]

The issue:

When I switch the IIS Application Pool for ADFS from "Integrated" to "Classic" (Framework v 2.0), my Home Realm Discovery page won't show up on my browser.

When I switch things back to "Integrated" in the IIS Application Pool, the Home Realm Discovery page gets successfully drawn.

[image: The Home Realm Discovery page]

How do I get things set up so that the Home Realm Discovery page is drawn in the browser with IIS set to "Integrated"?

Comment: Hints: don't indent your text. That formats it like code. Also, don't use multiple lines in the title of an image - that makes it not work. Finally, this question is off topic for [SO]. I've voted to move it to [SF].

Comment: (Puzzled about editing advice, as I didn't indent the text, nor multiple lines in title -- still, I'll keep in in mind :-)

Comment: The first line of the text was indented four spaces. The captions of the images were on several lines.

Comment: In your question "How do I get things set up so that the Home Realm Discovery page is drawn in the browser with IIS set to "Integrated"?" you probably mean "Classic".  Or else I don't understand the question.

Comment: Could you give a little background on _why_ you need AD FS's app pool to be 'Classic'?  Why not just leave the app pool which was installed by AD FS alone?

Comment: It appears that when I installed VS 2010 on the ADFS server I clobbered the Application Pool settings. Thus the Application Pool for ADFS stayed at .NET 2.0 but all other application pools were changed to 4.0. This messed things up so that the HRD bypassing code caused crashes in Integrated. The solution was to restore the ADFS server back to a previous state where all App Pools were v 2.0.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I thought that WIF Modules needed IIS 7 and full .NET pipeline integration (Integrated Mode) as they are written in .NET. Also, what error do you get?